# silkscreen artifacts on pcb

Tags: pcb, silkscreen

I often see silkscreen prints between pads on pcbs. Especially I noticed this on "high voltage" designs (SMPS). What is the reason for that? Maybe it is to

- improve automatic inspection
- prevent for solder shorts
- increase the isolation characteristics (because of an other pollution degree?)

That are all guesses. I'm not sure about that. Maybe you can help?

[image]

Comment: It would surprise me if that is regular silk screen printing.  On those places, I would expect something to do with keeping high voltage from creeping into places it doesn't belong.  I can't imagine that regular silkscreen ink is rated for that.

Comment: My guess and hence not an answer: Improve manual inspection and maybe make certification easier as you have a separate layer to measure distances between critical points.